# Cannot cd to environmental variable set in ~/.bashrc though it seems to exist (Scientific Linux 6.10)

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, cd

I have a strange problem. I have a variable that I have exported in ~/.bashrc.

```
export NCARG_ROOT=/usr/local/ncl
```

In a terminal I can echo the variable, and it shows up correctly:

```
user@computer ~]$ echo $NCARG_ROOT
/usr/local/ncl
```

When I try to cd to it however, I get an error:

```
user@computer ~]$ cd $NCARG_ROOT
: No such file or directory.
```

The path (/usr/local/ncl) does indeed exist. It seems as though when the variable is executed it is empty to the shell (note that there should be something before the colon). Curiously a similar situation happens for the c-shell. I add the following line to the bottom of /etc/csh.cshrc and I get the same problem after switching shells:

```
setenv NCARG_ROOT /usr/local/ncl
```

*changes shell*

```
user@computer ~]$ cd $NCARG_ROOT
: No such file or directory
```

I have found a workaround. Adding the same export line to ~/.bash_profile seems to work. But by my understanding, this should work the way I originally had it, or am I missing something?

I am using Scientific Linux 6.10, which is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux rebuild.

Comment: Do you have an alias or shell function wrapping around `cd` that might interfere? Because I can't reproduce the error message with an empty or non-existent parameter, `cd ""` brings me to my home directory without any error.

Comment: What does `declare -p NCARG_ROOT | cat -v` show? Is there a trailing `^M` carriage return? If so, your `.bashrc` has Windows line endings and needs to be converted to UNIX format.

Comment: Note the error message; it should start `cd: ...`, not `: ...`. Your file has DOS line endings and `NCARG_ROOT` ends with a carriage return.

Comment: I checked the alias list and couldn't find any substitutes for `cd`. There is nothing wrapping around 'cd' that I am aware of. How could I check?

Comment: That's got to be it. I copied and pasted into .bashrc from a text file generated with Windows when I first set this up. Didn't know that would be an issue. I will try to regenerate the file and add manually. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I remade the .bashrc file from the backup in /etc/skel/ and this time manually inserted my additions. Works correctly now.